# AngularJs Grid - Not working when place the code under a event

Tags: angularjs

Here is the code.

Working version - Grid displays and page load.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>
    <link href="http://localhost:4090/Content/ng-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://localhost:4090/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4090/Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4090/Scripts/ng-grid-2.0.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        // main.js
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                     { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                     { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                     { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                     { name: "Enos", age: 34}];
            $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Non working version. Moved the grid code under a button click.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>
    <link href="http://localhost:4090/Content/ng-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://localhost:4090/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4090/Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4090/Scripts/ng-grid-2.0.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        // main.js
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.LoadGrid = function () {
                alert('');
                $scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                     { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                     { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                     { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                     { name: "Enos", age: 34}];
                $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button id="click" ng-click="LoadGrid()">
        Load Grid</button>
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Getting the error : - TypeError: Cannot set property 'gridDim' of undefined

Comment: post some code and be more specific if you want good answers and help otherwise you might get skimpy responses back :)

Comment: I have similiar question, and I get [answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19342597/1870830

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your ng-grid is initializing before you instantiate $scope.gridOptions, as as such it throws the undefined error. Also, if you change a $scope property programatically, you may need to use $apply to get your changes to display on the templates.

So what you need to do is make sure the data structures exist (even if they're empty) and call $apply when "starting" the data-grid:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.myData = [];
        $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
        $scope.LoadGrid = function () {
            alert('');
            $scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                 { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                 { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                 { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                 { name: "Enos", age: 34}];
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
```

Here is an edited plunkr from the ngGrid examples page, to show this working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SnJ9J0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Move the  Tag at the end before the last  (will also load faster).

I presume the error is because the javascript is loading before the html is ready.

Does the console error log says anything else?

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to define your gridOptions before the data actually gets there.  That's the gorgeous part about the way Angular binds data - just set the data to the $scope object that will eventually have data & your grid will be smart enough to update itself by an internal $watch on the data item.