# Angular ng-grid declare gridOptions in function

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm new to Angular, and I'm trying to declare `gridOption` for `ng-grid` within a function, because I don't want it to fire before the data comes from the server.
But if I do so, it cause an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'gridDim' of undefined
```

What is going on?

Comment: You can delay the creation of the grid, using contructs like `ng-if` and only when the data is available render the grid.

Comment: any specific reason you don't want to fire gridOptions ? You know you can also opt to hide the grid and display it only after data comes in ?

Comment: The problem is not that the grid not load immediately but the data not load at all because the error. @Chandermani - can you give me example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop rendering till the data arrives do something like

```
<div ng-if="contentAvailable">
   <ng-grid/>
</div>
```

In you controller when the data is available setup the gridoptions object, followed by  `contentAvailable` to true.